# How to make multiple input in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

So I'm working on a project in company, currently we're moving from Vue 2 to Vue 3, but not using composition API
So there's a component array-field, which extends vuetify's v-text-field, allowing us to create multiple inputs, and results from these inputs is sent to the backend as an array
This component looks like this:

```
    <template>
  <div
    ref="array_field"
    class="array_field__wrapper"
  >
    <v-text-field
      v-for="(element, index) in elements"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :key="index"
      v-model="elements[index]"
      :label="isFirstValue(index) ? labelText : ''"
      class="array_field"
      :rules="rules.name"
      dense
      outlined
      :class="{ 'indent_right': !isLastValue(index) }"
      :append-inner-icon="isEmptyArray ? null : $icons['mdi-close']"
      :append-icon="isLastValue(index) ? $icons['mdi-plus'] : null"
      @click:append="addValue(index)"
      @click:append-inner="deleteValue(index)"
      @update:modelValue="onInput"
      @blur="onBlur"
    >
      <template #message="{ message }">
        {{ translateError(errorMessage, message) }}
      </template>
    </v-text-field>
  </div>
</template>
  
<script>
import { isEmptyOrNil } from '@/utils'
  
export default {
  props: {
    value: Array,
    labelText: String,
    translateError: Function,
    errorMessage: String
  },
  data () {
    return {
      elements: !isEmptyOrNil(this.value) ? this.value : [''],
      isEmptyArray: isEmptyOrNil(this.value),
      rules: {}
    }
  },
  watch: {
    elements (value) {
      this.$emit('input', this.isEmptyArray ? [] : value)
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    if (!isEmptyOrNil(this.value) && isEmptyOrNil(this.value[0])) {
      this.setLabelPositionOnTop()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isFirstValue (index) {
      return index === 0
    },
    isLastValue (index) {
      return index === this.elements.length - 1
    },
    addValue (index) {
      this.elements[index + 1] = ''
      this.isEmptyArray = false
      this.setLabelPositionOnTop()
    },
    deleteValue (index) {
      if (this.elements.length > 1) {
        this.elements.splice(index, 1)
      } else {
        this.elements = ['']
        this.isEmptyArray = true
        this.setLabelPositionByDefault()
      }
    },
    setLabelPositionOnTop () {
      const commonWrapper = this.$refs.array_field.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild
      const legendWrapper = commonWrapper.firstChild
      const labelWrapper = legendWrapper.nextSibling
      const label = labelWrapper.firstChild
      label.classList.add('v-label--active')
      const legend = legendWrapper.querySelector('legend').querySelector('span')
      legend.style.color = 'white'
      legend.style.fontSize = '12px'
      legend.style.textWrap = 'nowrap'
      legend.style.padding = '2px'
      const labelText = label.innerHTML
      legend.innerHTML = labelText
    },
    setLabelPositionByDefault () {
      const commonWrapper = this.$refs.array_field.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild
      const legendWrapper = commonWrapper.firstChild
      const labelWrapper = legendWrapper.nextSibling
      const label = labelWrapper.firstChild
      label.classList.remove('v-label--active')
      const legend = legendWrapper.querySelector('legend').querySelector('span')
      legend.innerHTML = '\u200b'
      legend.style.padding = 0
    },
    onInput (value) {
      this.isEmptyArray = false
      console.log(value)
    },
    onBlur () {
      if (!this.isEmptyArray) {
        this.setLabelPositionOnTop()
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Basically we have a dialog where we have multiple array-fields, we change them and send them to the backend, and we use array-field like this:

```
<isf-array-field
   v-model="authSource.add.ldap_phone"
/>
```

Data in dialog looks like this:

```
data () {
    const authSourceTemplate = {
      add: {
        name: null,
        url: null,
        base_dn: null,
        login: null,
        password: null,
        type: 'ldap',
        ldap_filter: null,
        ldap_phone: [],
        ldap_email: [],
        ldap_uuid: [],
        ldap_lastname: [],
        ldap_firstname: [],
        ldap_middlename: [],
        ldap_internal_phone: [],
        with_internal_phone: null
  
      }
    }
    return {
      authSourceTemplate: authSourceTemplate,
      authSource: this.clone(authSourceTemplate),
      actionPending: false,
      authSourcesDialogsProp: this.authsourcesDialogs,
      rules: {}
    }
```

So basically we use the fields from data() in v-model for an array-field, I don't know the logic behind it, but basically our array-field should return an array of strings

But my problem currently is that when I input something in text-field, v-model type changes from an array to string, and because of it i can't send the request to the backend
In previous version, where we used Vue 2, everything is okay, but with Vue 3 I have such problem and I can't figure out why

Comment: have you debugged it? there's also debugging functions in vue3

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev i tried debugging in devtools but i didn't really find the problem, what kind of debugging should i do?